# How to distinguish records in two different runs in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

For instance on Sept 1st there were 5 records in the report.
When the report ran on Oct 1st there were 7 records, so basically there were 2 new records added.
Is there way to mark/highlight those new records in the report export? They don’t have any date fields associated with them which makes job little challenging i guess.
Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a UFL (User Function Library) that provides functions for writing/reading info to/from text/excel/ini file/registry/database.

You would use one function from the UFL to lookup the info for the current record in one of these alternative data stores. If that info is found, you can suppress that record. And if it's not found, you would use another function from the UFL to write identifying info from the record so it can be looked up on the next run.

You can create your own UFL or see list of 3rd-party UFLs maintained by Ken Hamady [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you're using you could create a "command" in Crystal Reports, which both queries from database and writes back the records that were retrieved into some kind of a logging table.